# How to specify --gitignore argument in gh repo create cli command?

Tags: github, terminal, gitignore, github-cli

I'm trying to create remote repository using GitHub CLI and I can not find how to specify a particular gitignore file  with argument `--gitignore`, say, `github/gitignore/C++.gitignore`. There is an error `HTTP 422: Repository creation failed. (https://api.github.com/user/repos) gitignore_template is an unknown gitignore template.`

Unsuccessfully have been trying to find an example on internet and stackoverflow also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was implemented with [PR 3746](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/3746) for gh v1.12.0 (Q2 2021).

It is supposed to use only one word for the gitignore parameter.
Example:

```
gh repo create random --gitignore Go --license mit --public --confirm
```

In your case, try `--gitignore C++` or `--gitignore Cpp`.

Comment: Oh! The first I've done was `c++` without capital)) Thank you!